# Infinite matching of a subexpressions (regular expressions) returns only one match

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression like this (much simplified):

```
^(ab)*$
```

And am matching against this:

```
abababababababab
```

When I run it through `preg_match`:

```
preg_match('/$(ab)*$/', 'abababababababab', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abababababababab
    [1] => ab
)
```

Wheras I expect this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abababababababab
    [1] => ab
    [2] => ab
    [3] => ab
    [4] => ab
    [5] => ab
    [6] => ab
    [7] => ab
    [8] => ab
}
```

How can I get what I expect?

(Note that the subexpression could be more complicated, e.g. `([aA][bB])`, and I want the matched expressions in their order in the subject.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it by using `preg_match_all` like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(ab)/', 'abababababababab', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Remember that `preg_match` only provides the first match and that `preg_match_all` has the same functionality, but returns all. Also note that now the regular expression has changed. If you use the asterisk, it'll likely consume the entire string on the first match. You could, however, try something like `(ab)*?` to make it nongreedy.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, strager. ;-)